# strconv.Atoi in Go (Basic calculator)

Tags: go, calculator, strconv

**I'm trying to make a basic adding calculator in Go (complete noob here), but every time I'm getting an output of 0.**

**This is the code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    //"flag"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main(){
     reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
     fmt.Print("What's the first number you want to add?: ")
     firstnumber, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
     fmt.Print("What's the second number you want to add?: ")
     secondnumber, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
     ifirstnumber, _ := strconv.Atoi(firstnumber)
     isecondnumber, _ := strconv.Atoi(secondnumber)
     total := ifirstnumber + isecondnumber
     fmt.Println(total)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bufio.Reader.ReadString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) returns data up until and including the separator. So your string actually ends up being `"172312\n"`. `strconv.Atoi()` doesn't like that and returns 0. It actually returns an error but you're ignoring it with `_`.

You can see what happens with [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/4BHVMerIsq):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main(){
     ifirstnumber, err := strconv.Atoi("1337\n")
     isecondnumber, _ := strconv.Atoi("1337")
     fmt.Println(err)
     fmt.Println(ifirstnumber, isecondnumber)
}
```

You can trim the newlines with [`strings.Trim(number, "\n")`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim).